# Can't install kivy with Python 3.10.0

Tags: python, pip, kivy

I'm new to python. I'm getting an error when installing **kivy** with ***pip install kivy***

```
C:\Users\Acer>pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
  Using cached Kivy-2.0.0.tar.gz (23.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-wd83fnja\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gfj6fhoh\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.24,<=0.29.21,!=0.27,!=0.27.2' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew_dev~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (10 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-59.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.21,>=0.24
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1
    Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1 (from versions: 0.4.2, 0.4.3)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/96/091ddacafb84dd18555a32d860dbfaf9c806147aa30c6f3c8b93cb7bab97/Kivy-2.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=d25e44eb44e43762b2fd0c5874e51954e0f1181fd9800d8a6756be6d084812d8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/kivy/). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-wd83fnja\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gfj6fhoh\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.24,<=0.29.21,!=0.27,!=0.27.2' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew_dev~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Help please

Comment: Kivy 2.0 supports Python 3.6 - 3.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/releases/tag/2.0.0

> Currently supported Python versions are 3.6 - 3.9.

To sum it up, you will have to wait for a while for the developers of the Kivy project to package the library to 3.10. Meanwhile, you can still use Kivy on Python 3.9 without any issue

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem. Infinite loop of downloads and dependencies errors, as it can't work with Python version 3.10 yet.

Download one of the older Python 3.9 versions for this project (as multiple interpreter versions can coexist on the same machine)  if you can't wait for the update.

If you use PyCharm, you can create new project in venv, selecting 3.9 version of the interpreter and in the terminal run:

```
python -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples
```